# Getting installation error when installing awsebcli on a linux machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, circleci

I am getting a new error (only 2 days ago) when deploying to AWS Linux using CircleCI.

It seems that the sys_platform is picked as win32, while i am on a Linux box.

Not sure if this is a python version issue, since i am using python 2.7, or if it a sys_platform variable, since i am on Linux, but sys_platform is showing win32 below.

i am also not sure if this is also due to aws automatic update? Any help is appreciated.

How can this be fixed?
{

```
Failing command: Install awsebcli 
    Exit code: 1 
    Output: 
    nimal (2.7.9-2+deb8u2) over (2.7.9-2+deb8u1) ...
    Preparing to unpack .../libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.9-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.9-2+deb8u2) over (2.7.9-2+deb8u1) ...
    Preparing to unpack .../libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.9-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.9-2+deb8u2) over (2.7.9-2+deb8u1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libpython2.7:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../libpython2.7_2.7.9-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.9-2+deb8u2) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libpython2.7-dev:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../libpython2.7-dev_2.7.9-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libpython2.7-dev:amd64 (2.7.9-2+deb8u2) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-support.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-support_1.0.15_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-support (1.0.15) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libtimedate-perl.
    Preparing to unpack .../libtimedate-perl_2.3000-2_all.deb ...
    Unpacking libtimedate-perl (2.3000-2) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libdpkg-perl.
    Preparing to unpack .../libdpkg-perl_1.17.27_all.deb ...
    Unpacking libdpkg-perl (1.17.27) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package dpkg-dev.
    Preparing to unpack .../dpkg-dev_1.17.27_all.deb ...
    Unpacking dpkg-dev (1.17.27) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package build-essential.
    Preparing to unpack .../build-essential_11.7_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking build-essential (11.7) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libfakeroot:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../libfakeroot_1.20.2-1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libfakeroot:amd64 (1.20.2-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
    Preparing to unpack .../fakeroot_1.20.2-1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking fakeroot (1.20.2-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-perl.
    Preparing to unpack .../libalgorithm-diff-perl_1.19.02-3_all.deb ...
    Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.02-3) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl.
    Preparing to unpack .../libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-3+b1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-3+b1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-merge-perl.
    Preparing to unpack .../libalgorithm-merge-perl_0.08-2_all.deb ...
    Unpacking libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-2) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libfile-fcntllock-perl.
    Preparing to unpack .../libfile-fcntllock-perl_0.22-1+b1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libfile-fcntllock-perl (0.22-1+b1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libpython-dev:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../libpython-dev_2.7.9-1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libpython-dev:amd64 (2.7.9-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-ply.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-ply_3.4-5_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-ply (3.4-5) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-pycparser.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-pycparser_2.10+dfsg-3_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-pycparser (2.10+dfsg-3) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-cffi.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-cffi_0.8.6-1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking python-cffi (0.8.6-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-pkg-resources.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-pkg-resources_5.5.1-1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-pkg-resources (5.5.1-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-chardet.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-chardet_2.3.0-1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-chardet (2.3.0-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-colorama.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-colorama_0.3.2-1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-colorama (0.3.2-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-cryptography.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-cryptography_0.6.1-1+deb8u1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking python-cryptography (0.6.1-1+deb8u1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python2.7-dev.
    Preparing to unpack .../python2.7-dev_2.7.9-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking python2.7-dev (2.7.9-2+deb8u2) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-dev.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-dev_2.7.9-1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking python-dev (2.7.9-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-distlib.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-distlib_0.1.9-1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-distlib (0.1.9-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-html5lib.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-html5lib_0.999-3_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-html5lib (0.999-3) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-openssl.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-openssl_0.14-1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-openssl (0.14-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-ndg-httpsclient.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-ndg-httpsclient_0.3.2-1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-ndg-httpsclient (0.3.2-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-urllib3.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-urllib3_1.9.1-3_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-urllib3 (1.9.1-3) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-requests.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-requests_2.4.3-6_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-requests (2.4.3-6) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-setuptools.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-setuptools_5.5.1-1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-setuptools (5.5.1-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-pip.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-pip_1.5.6-5_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-pip (1.5.6-5) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-pyasn1.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-pyasn1_0.1.7-1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-pyasn1 (0.1.7-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package python-wheel.
    Preparing to unpack .../python-wheel_0.24.0-1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking python-wheel (0.24.0-1) ...
    Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
    Setting up libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.9-2+deb8u2) ...
    Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.9-2+deb8u2) ...
    Setting up libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.9-2+deb8u2) ...
    Setting up python2.7 (2.7.9-2+deb8u2) ...
    Setting up libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.9-2+deb8u2) ...
    Setting up libpython2.7-dev:amd64 (2.7.9-2+deb8u2) ...
    Setting up python-support (1.0.15) ...
    Setting up libtimedate-perl (2.3000-2) ...
    Setting up libdpkg-perl (1.17.27) ...
    Setting up dpkg-dev (1.17.27) ...
    Setting up build-essential (11.7) ...
    Setting up libfakeroot:amd64 (1.20.2-1) ...
    Setting up fakeroot (1.20.2-1) ...
    update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode
    Setting up libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.02-3) ...
    Setting up libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-3+b1) ...
    Setting up libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-2) ...
    Setting up libfile-fcntllock-perl (0.22-1+b1) ...
    Setting up libpython-dev:amd64 (2.7.9-1) ...
    Setting up python-ply (3.4-5) ...
    Setting up python-pycparser (2.10+dfsg-3) ...
    Setting up python-cffi (0.8.6-1) ...
    Setting up python-pkg-resources (5.5.1-1) ...
    Setting up python-chardet (2.3.0-1) ...
    Setting up python-colorama (0.3.2-1) ...
    Setting up python-cryptography (0.6.1-1+deb8u1) ...
    Setting up python2.7-dev (2.7.9-2+deb8u2) ...
    Setting up python-dev (2.7.9-1) ...
    Setting up python-distlib (0.1.9-1) ...
    Setting up python-html5lib (0.999-3) ...
    Setting up python-openssl (0.14-1) ...
    Setting up python-ndg-httpsclient (0.3.2-1) ...
    Setting up python-urllib3 (1.9.1-3) ...
    Setting up python-requests (2.4.3-6) ...
    Setting up python-setuptools (5.5.1-1) ...
    Setting up python-pip (1.5.6-5) ...
    Setting up python-pyasn1 (0.1.7-1) ...
    Setting up python-wheel (0.24.0-1) ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
    Processing triggers for python-support (1.0.15) ...
    Searching for six
    Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/six/
    Best match: six 1.12.0
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/bf/4138e7bfb757de47d1f4b6994648ec67a51efe58fa907c1e11e350cddfca/six-1.12.0.tar.gz#sha256=d16a0141ec1a18405cd4ce8b4613101da75da0e9a7aec5bdd4fa804d0e0eba73
    Processing six-1.12.0.tar.gz
    Writing /tmp/easy_install-aNdn0K/six-1.12.0/setup.cfg
    Running six-1.12.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-aNdn0K/six-1.12.0/egg-dist-tmp-l_0OC2
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    no previously-included directories found matching 'documentation/_build'
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    six: module references __path__
    Adding six 1.12.0 to easy-install.pth file

    Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six-1.12.0-py2.7.egg
    Processing dependencies for six
    Finished processing dependencies for six
    Downloading/unpacking urllib3==1.21.1
      Downloading urllib3-1.21.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (131kB): 131kB downloaded
    Installing collected packages: urllib3
      Found existing installation: urllib3 1.9.1
        Not uninstalling urllib3 at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
    Successfully installed urllib3
    Cleaning up...
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/socks.py:37: DependencyWarning: SOCKS support in urllib3 requires the installation of optional dependencies: specifically, PySocks.  For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contrib.html#socks-proxies
      DependencyWarning
    Downloading/unpacking awsebcli
      Downloading awsebcli-3.14.13.tar.gz (241kB): 241kB downloaded
      Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-Dq1hJk/awsebcli/setup.py) egg_info for package awsebcli
        error in awsebcli setup command: Invalid environment marker: sys_platform == "win32" and python_version >= "3.6"
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        error in awsebcli setup command: Invalid environment marker: sys_platform == "win32" and python_version >= "3.6"

    ----------------------------------------
    Cleaning up...
    Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Dq1hJk/awsebcli
    Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
    Exited with code 1
    The rest of your commands were successful: 
    •   Spin up Environment
    •   Checkout code
    •   Restoring Cache
    •   yarn install
    •   Saving Cache
```

}

Answer (score 6):

i went back to the logs in CircleCI and found out that the latest awsebcli version that worked correctly was 3.14.11
so i modified the following line in .circleci/config.yml

from

```
sudo pip install awsebcli --upgrade
```

to

```
sudo pip install awsebcli==3.14.11
```

everthing worked ok after

Answer (score 2):

The failure to install is due to an outdated version of `setuptools`. Upgrade `pip` to version 19+ and setuptools to version 40+.

Comment: so even if i am using python 2.7 and the error message says:                                      
                  and python_version >= "3.6" ?

Comment: Yes, because this is a problem parsing the contents of `setup.py`. The error does not necessarily say the problem is with Python 2.7. The error says "Invalid environment marker". A simple search of that term on Google returns [this link](https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/issues/358).